# Raspbian and Logitech K400 on PI4B

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster

It a fresh install of raspbian (10 buster) on a Raspberry PI4B. I use a Logitech K400. the keyboard and mouse are discovered at boot. But the touchpad does not go to the right end of the screen, it stops about 5 centimeters!
I cannot use some control! I have created `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_logitech_hidpp.conf` with `options hid_logitech_hidpp disable_raw_mode=1` ...no idea more,  help please!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but my Logitech K400r worked on a fresh install
after I turned on the keyboard and installed fresh batteries Duh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).